# Continuity of parametric integral $I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln{(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}}{x^2-1}dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence, parametric

How to prove that parametric integral $I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln{(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}}{x^2-1}dx$ is differentiable on $(1,\infty)$?
I wrote $I(\alpha)$ as $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}}{x^2-1}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln{(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}}{x^2-1}dx=I_1(\alpha)+I_2(\alpha)$, but I'm having difficulties to show that $I_2(\alpha)$ is differentiable on $(1,\infty)$.
Since
$f(x,\alpha)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln{(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}}{x^2-1}, 0<x<1\\
\alpha^2, x=1
\end{cases}$
and $f'(x,\alpha)$ are continuous on $[0,1)\times (1,\infty)$, $I_1(\alpha)$ is continuous on $(1,\infty)$, am I right?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand the question much but $x=\sec\theta$ substitution may help...

Comment: Are you fine with a complex-analytic proof?

Comment: @C-RAM You can post the answer, I hope that I will understand. Now, I'm interested to know why $\int_0^\infty \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2}dx$ converges uniformly, if I could prove that, I think that I would conclude why formula for $I(\alpha)$ holds.

Comment: For $\big|\alpha\big|>1\, \ln(1-\alpha^2+x^2\alpha^2)$ and the integral itself are not well defined ($1-\alpha^2+x^2\alpha^2$ becomes negative at some $x<1$)

Comment: For $\alpha\in[0;1]\,\, I(\alpha)=2\pi\arcsin\alpha$

Comment: @Svyatoslav This means that to find formula for $I(\alpha)$ I have to look interval $[0,1)$. Now I'm having problem to show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2}$ converges uniformly for $\alpha\in [0,\alpha_0]$, where $\alpha_0<1$. Is this something trivial or ? I just can't see it.

Comment: At $\alpha>1\,\, I(\alpha)$ is not a single-valued function and should be redefined. Technically it comes from the fact that the expression under the logarithm sign goes through zero and becomes negative - the logarithm branch should be defined itself. I think that without these steps there is no much sense to discuss any properties of $I(\alpha)$. Regarding the second integral: at $0\leqslant\alpha<\alpha_0\in[0;1)$ the integrand does not have singularities, and the integral can be evaluated directly (is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}$), so the uniform convergence follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually a standard complex analytic procedure to show an even stronger result; $I_2(\alpha)$ is analytic over $D=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{C}:\mathfrak{R}(\alpha)>1\}$. It hinges on [Morera's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).

Let $\gamma$ be a closed $C^1$ contour in $D$. Since for every $\alpha\in D$ the absolute value of the integrand grows asymptotically as $O(x^{-2}\ln(x))$) and thus is integrable over $\gamma\times(1,\infty)$, then through [Fubini's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), we may exchange the order of integration in the following double integral as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\oint_\gamma I_2(\alpha)d\alpha
&=\oint_\gamma\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}{x^2+1}dxd\alpha\\
&=\int_1^\infty\oint_\gamma\frac{\ln(1-\alpha^2+\alpha^2x^2)}{x^2+1}d\alpha dx\\
&=0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the last equality is due to Cauchy's integral theorem, since the integrand is analytic over $D$ for all $x>1$. We have just proven that
\begin{equation}
\oint_\gamma I_2(\alpha)d\alpha=0
\end{equation}
for all closed piecewise $C^1$ contours on $D$, and thus by Morera's theorem $I_2(\alpha)$ is analytic on $D$. This immediately implies that it is (real) differentiable on $(1,\infty)$.